# Jquery Array - AJAX PHP Autocomplete input

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I am trying to create an autocomplete input using AJAX / PHP but the array returned from PHP seems to be breaking it.

The idea is to have the flavour name and flavour company name show in a dropdown / expanded div that the user can select.

**The Array as it is returned to AJAX success (data):**

[image: [IMG]]

**The Array as JSON:**

[image]

I want to get the `flavour_name` value and the `flavour_company_name` value to put in the box as a string, then on selection grab them both as an array consisting of - `flavour_name` / `flavour_company_name` to put into a `DB` later.

I've tried using `JSON.stringify`, creating a `var obj` I have got it to return 1 value but not a list like I want.

All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

**My AJAX**

```
$("#flavour-name-input").keyup(function(){

    var token = '<?php echo json_encode($token); ?>';
    var search = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controllers/recipeControl.php",
    data: { token: token, search: search },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF no-repeat 165px");
    },
    success: function(data){

        //var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        $("#suggesstion-box").show();

        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        //$("#suggesstion-box").html(obj['flavour_name']);
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
    }
    });
});
```

**My PHP Controller**

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' && isset($_POST['token']) 
        && json_decode($_POST['token']) === $_SESSION['token']){
            $search = $_POST['search'];
            echo json_encode($flavours->getAllFlavoursSearch($search));
        }

}
```

**My PHP Function**

```
/**
    GET ALL FLAVOURS FOR SEARCH
*/
public function getAllFlavoursSearch($search) {
    $query = 'SELECT flavour_name, flavour_company_name FROM flavours WHERE flavour_name LIKE :search ORDER BY flavour_name ASC LIMIT 0,100';
    $stmt = $this->queryIt($query);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':search', '%'.$search.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
return $this->resultset();
}
```

Comment: since you are using JQuery, why don't use the autocomplete of JQuery ? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Because I want to learn more about jQuery, thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to achieve this in your controller. Now you are returning the json and this is treated like a string. I would create an array in the controller and then you loop it and create the html.

```
 <?php    
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' && isset($_POST['token']) 
            && json_decode($_POST['token']) === $_SESSION['token']){
                $search = $_POST['search'];
                $html = '<ul>';
                $content = $flavours->getAllFlavoursSearch($search);
                foreach ($content as $con) {
                    $html .= '<li><a href="">'.$con['flavour_name'].'-'.$con['flavour_company'].'</a></li>';
                }
                $html .= '</ul>';
                echo $html;
            }

    }
?>
```

I have not tested it but is something like this, maybe you have to check that the query returns an array.

Regards.

Comment: Amazing.. Thankyou very much, that worked a treat and has helped me immensely